# Tests to establish correlation

Tags: time-series, correlation

I'm trying to analyze if there exists any correlation between two time series? So far I have not been able to notice any significant correlation. 
So if I were to assert in my report that these time series are uncorrelated what are the minimum experiments/tests/metrics/results that I must provide to support my claim?

Comment: How are you assessing correlation?

Comment: Just by eye-balling the plots it is quite apparent that there is no correlation. However, I tried to remove as much noise as possible and analysed the scatter plots. Also I calculated the correlation coefficient which turns out to be -0.1648. However, having negative correlation makes no sense to the data, so I feel the value is a bit spurious.

Comment: Are you looking only at one lag? What about cross-correlations? When you say 'remove as much noise as possible', how are you doing that?

Comment: Yes I looked at one lag. Actually only 1 or 2 lags matters, beyond that even if there was some correlation I would not be able to explain it. Noise removal: One of my time series comes from text, so I did some more processing on the text to make it cleaner and I also tried some gaussian smoothing.

Comment: Right. Broadly speaking it sounds like you're doing fairly reasonable things to start with. The answer you have seems to be making useful, typical suggestions; usually the within-series structure is removed before looking for cross-series structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cross correlation and covariance functions are used to tell if there is a correlation between two time series, often ofset by some lead or lag as one time series leads the other and the correlation comes from some later time period in the response time series.  environmental time series, for example often have this lead/lag relationship where some cause (i.e. temperature change) leads to a correlated time series that lags it (i.e. growth of some type of tree). The CCF can be helpful is showing which time series leads and which lags each other which is often helpful for prediction. The definition of CCF is:

Cross Covariance Func:
$\gamma_{x,y}(s,t) = Cov(X_s,Y_t) E[(X_s-\mu_x(s))(Y_t-\mu_y(t))]$

Cross Correlation Func:
$\rho_{x,y}(s,t) = \frac{\gamma_{x,t}(s,t)}{\sqrt{\gamma_x(s,s)\gamma_y(t,t)}}$

Here's the vignette from R to calculate CCF:

http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/acf.html

And here is it for matlab:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/crosscorr.html

Here's an idea of what the output looks like:

[image]

You can also print out a vector of as many lags as you like to see what the correlation actually is numerically between the two series at different lag points.  Like I said up top, if you can see which series leads which, and by how many lags, a regression model with lagged observations from the predictor can be produced.

$Y_t = X_{t-1} + \epsilon$

Hope this helps.  Let me know if this isn't what you were looking for.

Comment: This sounds great. Yes, this sounds exactly like something I was looking for. Although as a general practice, how far do people go before they conclusively claim that there is no significant correlation in the data?

Comment: The blue bars are the confidence interval.  I'd have to double check, but I believe that they represent a 95% confidence.  So anything within the blue bars of the graph are statistically insignificant correlation, and anything outside of the bars is significant.  The CCF also uses complete.cases in R, so missing values aren't used.  So if you've got a bunch of missing data, then the CCF might not be accurate.